# g-mail app: download without an attachment

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, email, gmail

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2. I use GMail, and I am using the GMail app on this phone.

Is there a way to have emails downloaded to my phone *without* the attachments?  So when I open the email I have the option to download the attachment, if I chose to? If not: is there another email client/app you would recommend?

Answer (score 2):

I have an SGS2 too. The GMail app never downloads your attachments automatically. You'll see a list of the attachments at the bottom of the email, with the *option* to download them. The attachments get downloaded (and the corresponding bandwidth used) only when you press download. You can already safely read the email without worrying about GMail using up your bandwidth.

Comment: thanks.  I did not realize that the attachements were not really downloaded till you open them.  issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the GMail app (as I rarely use it). But for my normal mail via IMAP I use [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9), which lets me configure the size limit per mail to download (defaulting to 25kB AFAIR). Attachments are only loaded when you hit the button to tell the app you want it. You can also read your GMail mails with *K-9*, so both parts of your question are covered.